# How to stop camera from saving a copy from my image when I take it inside my app

Tags: android, camera

I made an application that takes a picture and saves it in SD card, with an extension like (.x).
Everything is ok , but every time I take an image, it saves in two places: my dir and my camera directory.

My problem: How to stop it from saving in gallery ?

```
      Uri mHighQualityImageUri = generateTimeStampPhotoFileUri();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mHighQualityImageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 20);


     private Uri generateTimeStampPhotoFileUri() {

        Uri photoFileUri = null;
        File outputDir = getPhotoDirectory();
        if (outputDir != null) {
            Time t = new Time();
            t.setToNow();
            File photoFile = new File(outputDir, System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".x");
            photoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
        }
        return photoFileUri;
    }



     private File getPhotoDirectory() {
        File outputDir = null;
        String externalStorageStagte = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (externalStorageStagte.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            File photoDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/mariam.billing/files");
            outputDir = new File("/sdcard/Billing/");
            if (!outputDir.exists())
                if (!outputDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            this,
                            "Failed to create directory "
                                    + outputDir.getAbsolutePath(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    outputDir = null;
                }
        }
        return outputDir;
    }

int x=0;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (this.requestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageHolder.setImageURI(mHighQualityImageUri);
            x=1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "but every time i take an image it save two placess my dir and gallery" -- a gallery is not a place. It is an app. If you ask the camera app to save the photo in a public place, that photo may get indexed by the `MediaStore` and shown in gallery apps. Use `FileProvider` so you can ask the camera app to save the photo to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/Camera/FileProvider) shows the basics of using `FileProvider` for photos.

Comment: my camera directory  , sorry .

Comment: i want to the image to be saved in my dir only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not your fault. Your code looks correct, and the camera app on your device does respect your EXTRA_OUTPUT request.

But this app chooses to save a copy of the photo elsewhere. Try to install [Google Camera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera) from the Play Store. I believe that if you use it to fulfill your ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, you will get only one copy of the image.

Try some other apps from the Play Store, notably the [Open Camera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera). There, you can download the source code and learn what it actually does when you launch the intent.

There are thousands of camera apps, built in to different devices, and available for download. They behave and misbehave differently. If you need more consistent behavior, you can take the photos from your app, utilizing the Android camera API or one of the libraries that make such integration easier.

**Update** there happens to exist a live [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36932082) dating back to Aug'2011, wow!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting duplicate images is because you are using two camera applications at the same time(That is: The default camera and the one you are creating). You are calling an intent to the inbuilt camera and so, the default camera will save its own copy while your application does the same. You avoid creating a custom camera like those of Facebook,Instagram etc. But you can do code creatively, thats if you intend to do an image upload application. You can make your camera take pictures, and after an upload or end of that event, your application deletes the taken images. Or better do this, store your images in a hidden folder. You can make the storage folder hidden by including a dot(.) before the folder name, and again, at the end of your event, your application deletes that hidden folder. But again, its not really a good practice.